# AutoMapper - How map complex objects to simpler model

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I want map `Origin.CityId`  and  `Origin.StateId`  properties of
`Itinerary`  class to  `OriginCityId`  and  `OriginStateId`   properties
of  `ItineraryModel`  class.

Ex:  `Itinerary itinerary = Mapper.Map<Itinerary>(ItineraryModel);`

My ViewModel

```
public class ItineraryModel : BaseModel
{
    public int OriginCityId { get; set; }
    public int OriginStateId { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
}
```

My Entity

```
public class Itinerary : BaseEntity
{
    public City Origin { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping that tried do

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ItineraryModel, Itinerary>()
            .ForPath(x => x.Origin.CityId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OriginCityId))
            .ForPath(x => x.Origin.StateId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.OriginStateId))
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I would like to too `.ReverseMap()` but can't find right syntax.

Comment: may be this help https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: I don't see any problem with your mapping. Both forward (from `ItineraryModel` to `Itinerary`) and reverse (from `Itinerary` to `ItineraryModel`) are working. What is the problem/issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add two mappings for mapping to `Itenerary`

```
CreateMap<ItineraryModel, City>()
            .ForMember(city => city.CityId, expression => expression.MapFrom(itineraryModel => itineraryModel.OriginCityId))
            .ForMember(city => city.StateId, expression => expression.MapFrom(itineraryModel => itineraryModel.OriginStateId));

CreateMap<ItineraryModel, Itinerary>()
            .ForMember(itinerary => itinerary.Origin, expression => expression.MapFrom(itineraryModel => itineraryModel));
```

Similarly you can define reverse mappings manually if needed.

BTW `ReverseMap()` is not recommended by author

https://jimmybogard.com/automapper-usage-guidelines/

Comment: Yes, but if you do this kind of thing, `ReverseMap` is the perfect fit :)

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, I haven't tried yet but I think `ReverseMap` will work with above mappings.

Comment: Those settings are not needed with `ReverseMap`. It's the default flattening that gets reversed. https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html